# error: git credential-osxkeychain store died of signal 11 with bitbucket

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket / git on a Mac + Mountain lion. Everything was working perfectly, but suddenly I started getting the error when pushing to github:

```
error: git credential-osxkeychain store died of signal 11
```

It then asks for my password. I enter it correctly, and it returns the same error message as well as:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

`git pull` doesn't return anything in at all.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Which version of Git do you have installed?  And did you recently upgrade it?

Comment: Also, can you run the `push` command with `GIT_TRACE=2` in front?  For example, `GIT_TRACE=2 git push`.